# trim phone number with regex

Tags: regex

Probably an easy regex question.

How do I remove all non-digts except leading + from a phone number?

i.e.

012-3456 => 0123456
+1 (234) 56789 => +123456789

Comment: Is your phone number always in international format?

Comment: What language is this in?  A global regex could help if they are supported.

Comment: Is this actually possible to do with a single regex? You can remove all non-numbers/pluses with a single pass, but then you need another pass to remove all but the first plus I think...

Comment: @Mark: absolutely this can be done in a single regex. You can use assertions to check that the `+` isn't the first.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
/(?<!^)\+|[^\d+]+//g
```

will remove all non-numbers and leave a leading `+` alone. Note that leading whitespace will cause the "leave `+` alone" bit to fail. In .NET languages, this can be worked into the regex, in others you should strip whitespace first before passing the string to this regex.

Explanation:

`(?<!^)\+`: Match a `+` unless it's at the start of the string. (In .NET, use `(?<!^\s*)\+` to allow for leading whitespace).

`|` or

`[^\d+]+`: match any run of characters that are neither numbers nor `+`.

Before (using `(?<!^\s*)\+|[^\d+]+`):

```
+49 (123) 234 5678
  +1 (555) 234-5678
+7 (23) 45/6789+10
(0123) 345/5678, ext. 666
```

After:

```
+491232345678
+15552345678
+72345678910
01233455678666
```

Comment: Clever. `(?<!^)\+` is that like a negated look-ahead or something?

Comment: @Mark: It's a negative lookbehind. `(?<!^)` means "Assert that it is impossible to match the beginning of the string at the current position", and only then `\+` match a plus sign.

Comment: Right...that makes more sense :)

Comment: FYI, Python is one such language that only supports fixed-width look-behinds. i.e., it doesn't support `(?<!^\s*)`

Comment: I am looking similar Regix but I also want that there is no leading 0 or +. e.g. +49 (123) 234 5678 converts to 491232345678. and (0123) 305/5678, ext. 666 converts to 1233055678666. I am trying to change given regix but as i am new to regix so I am failing. any body help me?

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot! It's just a pity JS doesn't support look behind assertions.

Comment: Caution if using this in JS in 2023: negative lookbehind is supported in most major browsers now, but that's a very recent change. Safari 16.4 was the last to add support, and it does not work in older versions. https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you can do

```
public static String trimmed(String phoneNumber) {
   return phoneNumber.replaceAll("[^+\\d]", "");
}
```

This will keep all `+`, even if it's in the middle of `phoneNumber`. If you want to remove any `+` in the middle, then do something like this:

```
return phoneNumber.replaceAll("[^+\\d]|(?<=.)\\+", "");
```

`(?<=.)` is a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to see if there was a preceding character before the `+`.

```
System.out.println("[" + trimmed("+1 (234)++56789 ") + "]");
// prints "[+123456789]"
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I remove all non-digits except leading + from a phone number?

Removing `(` and `)` and spaces from `+44 (0) 20 3000 9000` results in the non-valid number `+4402030009000`.  It should be `+442030009000`.

The tidying routine needs several steps to deal with country code (with or without access code or `+`) and/or trunk code and/or punctuation either singly or in any combination.

Answer (score 1):

If global regular expressions are supported you could simply replace all characters that are not a digit or plus symbol:

```
s/[^0-9+]//g
```

If global regular expressions are not supported you could match as many possible number groups as might be valid in your given phone number format:

```
s/([0-9+]*)[^0-9+]*([0-9+]*)[^0-9+]*([0-9+]*)[^0-9+]*([0-9+]*)/\1\2\3\4/
```

Comment: Yes it does - you could make a case against it that it won't remove a `+` *inside* the string, but that seems unlikely for a phone number.

Comment: @Marcelo, there is + in the regex, please double check it

Comment: @Marcelo: how does this not handle the leading +?  The leading + is supposed to be included.  Can a phone number have +'s throughout?

Comment: The question specifically indicated a + at the front. But I take the point that this is unlikely, so I'll remove the -1.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly *possible* to do that all in one regex, but I prefer simpler regexs that will deal with the leading plus correctly and the leading and trailing whitespace:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
while (<DATA>) {
    print "DATA Read: \$_=$_";  #\n already there...
    s/\s*(.*)\s*/$1/g;
    $s=s/(^\+){0,1}//?$1:'';
    s/[^\d]//g;
    print "Formatted: $s$_\n====\n";
 }


 __DATA__
 012-3456
 +1 (234) 56789
          +1 (234) 56789
 1234-56789        |
 +12345+6789
```

Output:

```
DATA Read: $_=012-3456
Formatted: 0123456
====
DATA Read: $_=+1 (234) 56789
Formatted: +123456789
====
DATA Read: $_=         +1 (234) 56789
Formatted: +123456789
====
DATA Read: $_=1234-56789        |
Formatted: 123456789
====
DATA Read: $_=+12345+6789
Formatted: +123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace everything except digits and + to ''

```
/[^\d+]/
```

In Python,

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("[^\d+]","","+1 (234) 56789")
'+123456789'
>>>
```

Comment: @Marcelo, there is + in the regex, please double check it.

Comment: The question specifically indicated a + at the front. But I take the point that this is unlikely, so I'll remove the -1.

Comment: @Marcelo: the `+` inside a character class definition is not a metacharacter.

Comment: I know, @polygenelubricants. My original point was that the OP specified that a `+` at the front should be kept, not just any `+`.

Answer (score 0):

use perl,

```
my $number = // set it equal to phone number
$number =~ s/[^\d+]//g
```

This will still allow for a plus sign to be anywhere, if you want it to only allow a plus sign in the beginning, I will leave that part up to you.  You can't just have the entire answer given to you or else you won't learn.

Essentially what that does now, is it will replace anything in $number that is not a digit or a plus sign with an empty string

Answer (score -3):

You cannot simply remove the '+' symbol. It has to be treated like '00' and belongs to the country code. '+xx' is the same as '00xx'.

Anyway, handling phone numbers with regex is like parsing html with regex...nearly impossible because there are so many (correct) spelling formats.

My advice would be be to write a custom class for handling phone numbers and not to use regex.