# Java RegEx: For Phone number without leading space or 0 or +

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove leading 0 , + or any space (\s) before starting actual numeric character from phone numbers. Probably its not tough but as I am new to regix so I was looking for help. I tried to make my own but I was unsuccessful.

Here is the link which kind of same but it also adding leading + but I do not want that. [trim phone number with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711616/trim-phone-number-with-regex)

so for I attempted this but it also removed the inner 0

```
(^\s*|0*|[+]*)
```

I also tried this but its actually not working in java but only in Php so I want help for java based regix

```
^(?:\s*0+|[+]0*|(\d+)0*)(?!$)
```

Example Input

```
+490232345678
0049032345678
+1 (555) 234-5078
+7 (23) 45/6789+10
(0123) 345/5678, ext. 666
```

Desired out put

```
490232345678
49032345678
15552345678
72345678910
1233455678666
```

I just need regix because I alredy know that how to use that regix in java. 
I have this piece of code which need regix

```
    String value = "+490232345678";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^\s*|0*|[+]*)");      
    Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
    value = m.replaceAll("");
```

Comment: Buddy I do not need any code. I just searching Regular expression. I know how to write java code. But I was looking a regular expression that can work with my input

Comment: @Mubasher take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] testResult = {"+490232345678", 
                            "0049032345678", 
                            "+1 (555) 234-5078", 
                            "+7 (23) 45/6789+10", 
                            "(0123) 345/5678, ext. 666"};
    String reg = "^([\\(+ ]0| +|0+|\\(\\)|\\+)| +|[^\\d]+|/$";
    for (String phone : testResult) {
        System.out.println(phone.replaceAll(reg, ""));
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
490232345678
49032345678
15552345078
72345678910
1233455678666
```

An even simpler approach would be to do it in two steps:

```
 .replaceAll("[^\\d]+", "").replaceAll("^0+", "")
```

Remove all not numbers and then the leading zeros.

**RegEx Explanation**

```
^([\(+ ]0| +|0+|\(\)|\+)| +|[^\d]+|\/$

 1st Alternative ^([\(+ ]0| +|0+|\(\)|\+)
     ^ asserts position at start of the string
   1st Capturing Group ([\(+ ]0| +|0+|\(\)|\+)
       1st Alternative [\(+ ]0
           Match a single character present in the list below [\(+ ]
           \( matches the character ( literally (case sensitive)
           +  matches a single character in the list +  (case sensitive)
           0 matches the character 0 literally (case sensitive)
       2nd Alternative  +
           + matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
           + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
       3rd Alternative 0+
           0+ matches the character 0 literally (case sensitive)
           + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
       4th Alternative \(\)
           \( matches the character ( literally (case sensitive)
           \) matches the character ) literally (case sensitive)
       5th Alternative \+
           \+ matches the character + literally (case sensitive)
 2nd Alternative  +
    + matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
    + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
 3rd Alternative [^\d]+
    Match a single character not present in the list below [^\d]+
    + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    \d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
 4th Alternative \/$
    \/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
 $ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)
```

Source of Explanation: https://regex101.com/

And here is a visual representation from https://www.debuggex.com/

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jorge. Let me try this with my inputs.

Comment: Jorge , two steps are not possible in my application, in our application we have one generic validator which take regix input and replace the capturing groups to replacement string so i will go with your first regix. this validtor is generic can be applied to any type of data by just changing the regix and replacement.

Comment: jorge , it will be great help if you can explain a bit about how this is working. AS I am learner to regix and new bee in regix so that will be helpful to my understanding. if you have time then please.

Comment: Ok, will do, wait a bit!

Comment: Strange I was also trying on regex101.com but could not made myself. Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to use the double "\" because of Java?

Comment: No I was checking at http://www.regexplanet.com after making "^(?:\s*0+|[+]0*|(\d+)0*)(?!$)" from https://regex101.com